# When will we see Ubuntu smartphones in shops and/or on ebay?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

will we see Ubuntu smartphones in shops and/or on ebay?

Comment: Maybe, someday.

Comment: there is already some porting available, for example you can run Ubuntu ( not Ubuntu Touch, just the plain old Ubuntu ) on a Nexus 7 quite easily. There is probably something for the Nexus 4 too, maybe Ubuntu Touch, I don't remember because I don't follow this things.

Comment: @user2384250 What exactly is the difference?

Comment: @NoBugs with what ?

Comment: Ubuntu / Ubuntu touch - It's basically the same OS, but with QML/Javascript as the recommended app language correct? Using Ubuntu Touch would only mean most normal apps wouldn't work until you plug it in to monitor and keyboard correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the Ubuntu Insights blog post by Richard Collins, Ubuntu Product Management, [Get the FAQs about Ubuntu on smartphones](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305130003/http://insights.ubuntu.com/mobile/get-the-faqs-about-ubuntu-on-smartphones):

*"When will it be available to buy?*

*This depends mainly on our partners’ roadmaps, but we are working with these partners today and expect the Ubuntu to be available on phones during 4th quarter 2013 or in early 2014.*"